# Rails how to implement role and define role's power?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Now, in my rails app, I use simple authentication(email, password) and give account `role` to define what account can do.

```
  def login
    email = params[:email]
    @account = Account.find_by_email(email)
    if @account && @account.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @account.id
      redirect_to books_path
    else
      render :login
    end
  end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= Account.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

for example: two role manager(role_id:1) and user(role_id:2...N)
in controller, I use stupid way to set data for each role like:

**every book has account_id**

```
def index
    @books = Book.where("account_id = ?,@current_user.id)
    @books = Book.all if @current_user.role_id == 1
end
```

it seems so foolish, and I tried to use **cancancan** to solved this, but as I know, **cancancan** just can define for Restful method, and can distinguish role authority like manager can do all and method can do show... does **cancancan** can do some way to solved what role can see what data they own? use **cancancan** or other way to solved? please give me some advice! thanks.

Comment: could my answer help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the cancancan helper `:can?` for this

for example

define your abiliies for each role

```
can :read, Book
```

now cancancan check if your user with the specific role can read the book entries

or you check it (on other pages) with:

```
<% if can? :create, Book %>
  .....
<% end %>
```

you can also define your own abilities see the [wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities%20wiki) for detailed help